# How to refer to payments from Odoo invoice?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I am trying to loop through payments (account.payments) recorded for Odoo invoices (account.move). I would like to get display_name, payment_reference and amount from account.move.
How should I construct my search domain to match exactly the payments?
Here is the code:

```
def _export_invoice_with_payments(self):
    unique_id = self.name
    seller = self.company_id
    buyer = self.partner_id
    #...
    invoice_payments = self.env['account.payment'].search(
    [
    ('display_name', '=', self.name),
    ], limit = 50)

    for obj in invoice_payments:
       payment_display_name = obj.display_name
       payment_record_ref = obj.ref
```

It seems that my search domain is not correctly set. I tried also

```
invoice_account_moves = self.env['account.payment'].search(

[
    ('payment_transaction_id.invoice_ids', '=', self.id)
])
```

But that does not seems to work. What especially fails are POS-paid, Paytrail and Stripe paid invoices. Their payments are visible in the user interface (payments widget), but do not get in my loop.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Make a sale in POS. Set customer, payment method "Bank" and create invoice.
2. Close POS session. Validate entries and post.
3. Navigate on the POS sale to see the invoice (Three dots on POS -> Orders -> View sessions and select one -> Select basket to see the Orders -> Select Invoice to see the invoice. Now on the invoice there is clearly payment recorded, the invoice is validated and paid.

[image: Payment info widget shows that even POS session has payment recorded for the invoice.]

Or is there any better way to loop through invoice's recorded payments?

Answer (score 1):

You can try filter from all payments by reconciled_invoice_ids field.It will return all reconciled payments of current invoice. Check below code.

```
self.env['account.payment'].search([]).filtered(lambda p: self.id in p.reconciled_invoice_ids.ids)
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth. However, the filter does not detect invoices that have been paid by bank or cash on POS sales. 

Steps to reproduce:
- Create a sale in POS
- Set payment to be bank (debit card)
- Set to create the invoice
- Complete sale 

Now see the POS sessions, you will then follow from there to sales and Invoices. It is marked as paid on POSS/2022/07/0024 but the filter won't catch it.

Comment: @OssiMantylahti that's because the session hasn't been closed yet. Payments are reconciled when you close the session

Comment: The session *has* been closed and posted. Still, the filter search does not find payments for POS sales or invoices. Check my screen capture (updated). NB @MatíasSanturio